# Increase the length of a numpy array by repeating its elements?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Looking for a method which can be used to adjust the lenth of a `numpy array` by repeating its elements. I know this can be implemented in many ways. I am looking for the most elegant or `numpy` supported functionlities. Thanks to your input.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
input = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
# Increase its length to 11
expected_output = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: `np.resize(arr, 11)`

Comment: @user3483203: So, simple than expected! Sorry for this question without go throughing the docs completely. Neverthless, it might help someone who wants quick solution.